# Can I save my Django signals in an empty app

Tags: python, django

I want to implement signals for a number of my apps and for `django-contrib-comments`. Can't I just create an app, load it at the top of `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` *(After the django apps)* and then place all my signals inside the `views.py` file?

```
# > ./manage.py startapp signals
# > vim myapp/settings.py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    ...
    'signals',
    ...
}
...
# > vim signals/view.py
...
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from djanfo_comments.odels import Comment
from myapp.mymodels import MyModel

@receiver(post_save, sender=Comment)
def commentSaveSignal(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
...

@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def myModelSaveSignal(sender, **kwargs):
    ...
...
```

Comment: What exactly does not work as you expect it?

Comment: No I'm just wondering if this is a viable way to register signals as I do not know where to put the signals code for `django-contrib-commets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you can do that.

You will want your signals to be registered during startup. One way to do that is to make sure that `views` is imported during startup, eg from your `urls.py`.

I would, however, suggest to use the recommended way and register them in your app startup code (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)

As your `MyModelSaveSignal` is a method (and not a class), you should choose a lowercase name.

Comment: How do I register signals for packages such as `django-contrib-comments`? Where do I put them?

Comment: Can you import a `signals.py` file at the top of you base `urls.py`?

Comment: That's not the way to go. Please read the link provided above.

Comment: You can register your handlers for signals from other apps within you app. Which signal do you have in mind?

Comment: the `django-contrib-comments`. not to sure where to put it